# Spinnaker with Kubernetes: Not able to connect the docker hub repository

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

I'm trying to configure the spinnaker to deploy applications in kubernetes environment.

I followed a [documentation](http://www.spinnaker.io/docs/kubernetes-source-to-prod), 
at [step-3](http://www.spinnaker.io/docs/kubernetes-source-to-prod#section-3-create-a-demo-server-group) the containers are not showing up as shown in the [screenshot](https://files.readme.io/JRMxxbaSQ1mmD5VH8EtD_firstSG1.png). Then I moved to next [step](http://www.spinnaker.io/docs/kubernetes-source-to-prod#section-4-git-to-_dev_-pipeline)(Pipeline creation), when I select `type: Docker` in the `Automated Trigger`, again the `Repo name` is not showing up as shown in [screenshot](https://files.readme.io/ZV0WoYPyTQSwLJ1CvysC_dockertrigger.png).

**So, I'm suspecting there is problem with spinnaker and docker hub repo(Authentication/Misconfiguration?)**

I have copied the Kubernetes Authentication config file to `~/.kube/config`. I think there is no problem with spinnaker and kubernetes. When I create a `Load Balancer` in spinnaker I can see `Kube Services` are creating (test-dev & test-prod)

```
root@veeru:~# kubectl get services
NAME                CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes          192.168.3.1     <none>        443/TCP                      91d
test-dev            192.168.3.113   <none>        80/TCP                       6h
test-prod           192.168.3.185                 80/TCP                       6h
```

My `spinnaker-local.yml`

```
<Content removed for brevity>

  kubernetes:
    # For more information on configuring Kubernetes clusters (kubernetes), see
    # http://www.spinnaker.io/v1.0/docs/target-deployment-setup#section-kubernetes-cluster-setup

    # NOTE: enabling kubernetes also requires enabling dockerRegistry.
    enabled: true
    primaryCredentials:
      # These credentials use authentication information at ~/.kube/config
      # by default.
      name: veerendrav2
      namespace: default
      dockerRegistryAccount: veerendrav2

  dockerRegistry:
    # If you want to deploy containers to a container management solution,
    # you must specifiy where these container images exist first.

    # NOTE: Enabling dockerRegistry is independent of other providers.
    # However, for convienience, we tie docker and kubernetes together
    # since kubernetes (and only kubernetes) depends on this docker provider
    # configuration.
    enabled: true

    primaryCredentials:
      name: veerendrav2
      address: https://hub.docker.com
      repository: veerendrav2/spin-kub-demo

<Content removed for brevity>
```

My `/opt/spinnaker/config/clouddriver-local.yml`

```
dockerRegistry:
  enabled: true
  accounts:
    - name: veerendrav2
      address: https://hub.docker.com/ # Point to registry of choice
      username: veerendrav2
      password: password
      repositories:
        - veerendrav2/spin-kub-demo
```

My Sample application [github repo](https://github.com/veerendra2/spin-kub-demo) and [docker hub repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/veerendrav2/spin-kub-demo/)

Thanks

Comment: Veerendra, I'm facing the exact issue. Were you able to resolve it? Please let me know. Thx

Comment: Use latest version!

Answer (score 1):

In `/opt/spinnaker/config/clouddriver-local.yml` you likely need to change the `dockerRegistry.accounts[0].address` field to `https://index.docker.io`, since DockerHub's registry isn't hosted on `hub.docker.com`, but on `index.docker.io`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But still it is not working ;-(

Comment: I can see that this url is called internally to get images http://127.0.0.1:8084/images/find?provider=dockerRegistry .But its returning an empty array.

Comment: Maybe try removing the username & password in `clouddriver-local`, and set the lone repo to something public, like `library/nginx`. If that works, it's likely an auth issue.

Comment: Does the endpoint `localhost:7002/credentials` include any reference to the docker account you've configured?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to configure the docker registry address, or any other configs, is using [Halyard](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/halyard/). Modifying the config files directly could result in them getting overwritten.

You can add an account, or edit an existing one this way.

```
# Add a docker registry account
hal config provider docker-registry account add <ACCOUNT_NAME> --address https://index.docker.io

# Edit the account(i.e. add a repo)
hal config provider docker-registry account edit grizzthedj --add-repository <ACCOUNT_NAME>/<REPO>

# Deploy the changes
hal deploy apply
```